# How do I center an image if it's wider than its container?

Tags: css

Normally, you center images with `display: block; margin: auto`, but if the image is larger than the container, it overflows to the right. How do I make it overflow to the both sides equally? The width of the container is fixed and known. The width of the image is unknown.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***HTML***

```
​<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif" height="100" />
</div>​
```

***CSS***

```
.image-container {
    width: 150px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin:100px;
}

.image-container img {
    border: solid 1px green;
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$(".image-container>img").each(function(i, img) {
    $(img).css({
        position: "relative",
        left: ($(img).parent().width() - $(img).width()) / 2
    });
});
```

​

See it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4eYX9/30/

Comment: Perfect solution for me, that really made my day, i just added the same logic on height as well so it will match all my cases

http://jsfiddle.net/4eYX9/152/

Answer (score 112):

## A pure css solution

Requiring one extra wrapper (tested in FireFox, IE8, IE7):

### Improved Answer

There was a problem with the original answer (below). If the image is larger than the container that `outer` is centered on with it's auto margins, then it truncates the image on the left and creates *excessive* space on the right, [as this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/WAxn3/4/).

We can resolve that by floating `inner` right and then centering *from* the right. This still truncates the `img` off the page to the left, but it does so by explicitly pushing it that way and then centers back off of that, the combination of which is what prevents the *extra* horizontal scroll on the right. *Now we only get as much right scroll as we need in order to see the right part of the image.*

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WAxn3/6/) (Borders in fiddle are for demo only.)

**Essential CSS**

```
div.outer {
    width: 300px; /* some width amount needed */
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: visible;
}
div.inner {
    position:relative;
    float: right; /* this was added and display removed */
    right: 50%;
}
div.inner img {
    position: relative; 
    right:-50%; /* this was changed from "left" in original */
}
```

**If you desire *no* right scroll at all for wide images**

Then using the above, also set whatever element wraps `outer` ([like `body`](http://jsfiddle.net/WAxn3/7/) or [a third wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/WAxn3/8/)) to have `overflow: hidden`.

---

### Original Idea (for History)

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WAxn3/3/) (Borders in fiddle are for demo only.)

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="/yourimage.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.outer {
    width: 300px; /* some width amount needed */
    margin: 0 auto; 
    overflow: visible;
}
div.inner {
    display: inline-block; 
    position:relative; 
    right: -50%;
}
div.inner img {
    position: relative; 
    left:-50%; 
}
```

Comment: +1 - brilliant. Is `float: left` necessary in `.inner` style?

Comment: However, for the new revised solution, the `float: right` is required.

Comment: (+1) @ScottS: per chance, have you worked out a vertical centering equivalent??

Comment: Works great! The only thing I would add is a div with a 'clear class' at the end to clear both ---  .clear {clear:both;}  and <div class="clear"></div>

Comment: This is the best method. This should be accepted as the best answer

Comment: For my own purposes, I forked your fiddle to put it through its paces using an animate function.  It holds up very nicely!  Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/hSNBT/

Comment: I tried vertically with `bottom` and `top` but it didn't work. so I used `margin-top:50%' in `inner` and `margin-top:-50%` in `img` and worked in new chrome. you can try with other browsers

Comment: @VictorFerreira: This question and answer was only for horizontal centering, so vertical would be a different matter. FYI, if you are the one designing the web page, *you* should probably test it in other browsers to be sure it is going to give your users the best experience.

Comment: @ScottS 1- you = you all, and not you Scott. You all can test for other browsers if you need a vertical solution as well. 2- Faust asked for a 'vertical equivalent' (and probably most of other developers who got here) so i'm telling you what I did

Comment: NOTE: If you put explicit dimensions on the image itself (eg. for responsive design) you also need to apply those same dimensions (specifically the width) to the `.inner` class otherwise in IE the image won't be centered.

Comment: I know this is super old, but I put a simple pen together: http://codepen.io/daveobriencouk/pen/Xmzrdw

Comment: @DaveO'Brien: FYI: your codepen uses the original idea technique, rather than the improved version from the answer.

Comment: @ScottS You are right - sorry, it's been a long week. I've updated this pen to reflect this - I just noticed your fiddles making these pens kinda redundant. Anyway, your solution is excellent - thank you.

Comment: how come this doesn't work anymore - at least in Chrome. The horizontal scrollbar is back !

Comment: how about `width: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` ? http://jsfiddle.net/WAxn3/226/ - You also need to remove `border`, or change it to `outline`

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAxn3/6/) appears to be working fine for me in Chrome. You are missing the point of my fiddle I think, based off your "fixes." The purpose of this answer is to center an image within a container that is _smaller_ than the image itself. So my `width: 300px` and red border are showing the _smaller container_ in my fiddle, and showing that the image is centered in it. Now, I am getting some inconsistent issues with the horizontal scroll bar in Chrome for my fiddle (sometimes its shows, sometimes not). So I need to figure out if I can resolve it.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Scratch that, I have no horizontal scroll issues either. I was looking at the fiddle that did not have the `overflow: hidden` set, but you will notice in my answer that I address using `overflow: hidden` under "**If you desire *no* right scroll at all for wide images**" right below my css to eliminate any scroll at all from the image.

Comment: OK got it! sorry I missed that part. As you can see I used this answer months ago and when coming back to it for something else I saw this problem for the first time so feared it was a browser 'regression'. It seems to work to put width: 100% on 'outer' though along with hidden, no need to touch the parent as far as I can see. Seems to be working with an image much wider than my viewport. Thanks for taking the time to check :-)

Comment: Is it possible to add this approach in this example: http://codepen.io/osnysantos/pen/LbvEML/ ? Where I'm trying to center an image within a link with relative width. @ScottS

Comment: @OsnyNetto: It is a bit unclear what you need centered in the example. Your images there appear to control the width of the `a` (as they should), so you will not have an image "wider than its container" as this solution is for, correct?

Comment: @ScottS codepen updated! please note just the first image is not aligned because it's wider than parent div. I just create a wrapper div to try to get this image align with my list items. But I'm not sure it's needed. I'd like  to get my horizontal list (with uncertain width, it will depend on text) to get the child (<img>) centered with it. Please look this image to know exactly what I'm talking about: https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/0w1p040T1k3P3R0C0p2t/Image%202016-12-23%20at%208.58.05%20AM.png that's it, the image could be wider or narrow than my list item.

Comment: @Osny: I think your problem will be the "with uncertain width, it will depend on text" statement. The CSS only solution here requires a set `width` on the outer element (`div.outer` in my example), which means essentially a set width on your `a` element. I think for any flexible width solution, you will have to use [one of the javascript solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3300749/369707).

Comment: Great technique, works like a charm. For others that need to add more child nodes, you might need to `clear` floating first as seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp). So it can display properly.

Comment: Great technique, works like a charm. For others that need to add more child nodes, you might need to `clear` floating first as seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp). So it can display properly.

Answer (score 49):

Here's a 2 line CSS solution (a couple more lines might be required for cross-browser support):

```
img {
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternative pure CSS solution is to use `transform` attribute:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <img class="image" src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 100px; /* for demo */
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

img.image {
    width: 200px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuermosi777/q9mLtzoz/1/)

Just to add a `overflow:hidden` to parent `div` to hide the extra area of the image.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to set it as [background image](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) of the container instead.

```
#container {
    background: url('url/to/image.gif') no-repeat center top;
}
```

Comment: @Cannibal: ah, I now understand what you meant with your "can't overflow". It certainly does, you just want the overflow to be **visible**. No, that's indeed not possible with only CSS background image. It's only useful when you want to have it on a `<body>`.

Answer (score 4):

In fact there is a simpler pure css/html way (without large horizontal scroll) :

**Html** :

```
<div class="outer">
  <img src="/my/sample/image.jpg">
</div>
```

**Css** :

If you don't want to see image overflow

```
div.outer img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    z-index:-1;
}
div.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}
```

With image overflow visible

```
div.outer img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    z-index:-1;
}
div.outer {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}
body, html {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

A **background** solution with image overflow visible :

**Html** :

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**Css** :

```
div.outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
div.inner {
    background: url('/assets/layout/bg.jpg') center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
}
```

assuming outer is in a width specified container.

Answer (score 3):

I see this is an old post, so maybe everybody knows this by now, but I needed help for this and I solved it using flex:

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
   /* give it the width and height you like */

}

.parent img {
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: To [align Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) 
`align-items` and `justify-content` can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I can only think of a Javascript solution since what you need to do is relatively position the image a negative amount to the left of its container:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var theImg = $('#container img');
    var theContainer = $('#container');
    if(theImg.width() > theContainer.width()){
        theImg.css({
            position: 'relative',
            left: (theContainer.width() - theImg.width()) / 2
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a more elegant solution, without flex, similar to something above, but more generalized (applies on both vertical and horizontal):

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* height: 100%; */ /* optional */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a pure CSS solution (Except for the next answer :)).  However with Javascript it would be just a matter of finding the width of the image, subtracting the container width, dividing by two and you have how far to the left of the container you need.