# How to use max height and height if you have two divs

Tags: html, css

I have the following DOM:

```
<div id="parent" style="height: 200px;">
  <div id="header" style="height: 40px;"></div>
  <div id="content" style="max-height: 100%; overflow-y: auto"></div>
</div>
```

This leads to content having a height of `200px` although I want it to be `160px`. Basically the parent div is of variable height and I want the content div to have the height based on it. The header height is fixed.

I cannot use js to solve this, as the actual dom is very convoluted and using JS for it would just make it further complex.

Comment: Since you are defining all of the heights in pixels, why don't you just apply `max-height: 160px` on `#content`? There's no reason why `max-height: 100%` would limit the height of that div to 160px.

Comment: The parent height is variable. And is not actually 200px. It varies based on the window size. I checked similar questions, and it seems I would have to implement flex here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262938/child-with-max-height-100-overflows-parent

Comment: I am aware of that question. Thanks to it I was able to reach till here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
#parent {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
#header {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: red;
}
#content {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just in case, need to add overflow-y: auto to the content.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling the **header** out of the main flow works?

```
<div id="parent" style="height: 200px;position:relative;">
  <div id="header" style="height: 40px;position:absolute; top:0;"></div>
  <div id="content" style="padding-top:40px;max-height: 100%; overflow-y: auto"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with calc()

```
#content {
  max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  background:tomato
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q5mngpfm/)

Alternatively, you could make use of box-sizing to do this:

```
#content {
  padding-top:40px;
  margin-top:-40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:-1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q5mngpfm/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

How about using calc()?

```
#content {
  height: calc(100% - 40px); 
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/upemxmmf/

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#parent {
  background: teal;
  height: 200px;
}

#header {
  background: coral;
  height: 40px;
}

#content {
  background: #eee;
  max-height: calc(100% - 40px); /* 100% - height of header */
  overflow-y: auto
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbp59c55/)**

[About calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and 
[calc() support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)