# Laying out elements relative to a sibling with max-height:100%

Tags: css

I am building a lightbox which contains an article and some nav buttons which are positioned relative to the article (see pic). The article can be a variable length/height, but no bigger than the parent - the content should scroll with `overflow:auto`.

[image]

I've tried to build this using `max-height:100%`, but as mentioned in this question- [Child with max-height: 100% overflows parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262938/child-with-max-height-100-overflows-parent) , if the parent element doesn't have an explicit height set, `max-height` resolves to `none`, so `overflow:auto` doesn't trigger. However, setting a height on the parent means the buttons are no longer positioned relative to the dynamic article height.

You can see a demo of this here: https://jsbin.com/hepivelele/edit?html,css,js,output

Click 'run with JS' then click anywhere in the demo to add more content to the article so it's longer than the page. Giving `#wrap` `height:100%` shows the opposite problem mentioned above.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: This might give you an idea although I haven't solved the problem: https://jsbin.com/modozuxona/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: If I correctly understand what you want, you may add `max-height: 90vh;` to `article`.

Comment: Could you provide the full code you have?

Comment: @FaustoNA thanks but im not sure what your plan is?

Comment: @somethinghere full code is in the jsbin demo linked in the question

Comment: I am sorry I most honestly don't remember what I was trying to do hah. I think I was trying to make a new div in order to transfer the conflicting attributes like overflow for them not to affect your buttons. I really gotta go to sleep now though :)

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand what you want, but just adding `max-height: 90vh;` to `article` element (and no other changes, see https://jsbin.com/kofepotiji/edit?css,output) makes it work like my understanding of what you are trying to achieve: buttons are in the right positions and `overflow:auto` works like expected. The only drawback - is that on really small heights padding of `#lightbox` becomes bigger than 10vh.

Comment: @SergiyT. wow, that works great :-D do you want to post that as an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `max-height: 90vh;` to `article` element. Than it starts working without any other changes to markup or style.

Check modified example: https://jsbin.com/kofepotiji/edit?css,output

Current browser support is rather good: http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

The only drawback is that on really small heights padding of `#lightbox` becomes bigger than 10vh. This may be fixed by changing padding from `px` to `vw` and `vh`, but it occurs if height of viewport is less than 600-700px.