# Fitting picture into div

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-framework-7

I am facing problem with fitting picture into div. Basically divs are the cards headers. Pictures are in different orientation and also size. What should I do to fit them in ?

[Photo in div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ebju.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some markup.

Comment: Hard to answer without any information on your code. You could however take a peek here and see if that's useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262938/child-with-max-height-100-overflows-parent/14264093#14264093

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this trick and works really well for me:

```
<div class="card" style="background-image: url(...)"></div>
```

And the the CSS:

```
.card {
   background-size: cover;
   height: 400px;
   width: 600px;
}
```

The point is to scale the image using the `cover` background sizing method that shows most of the image and also covers the whole div so your items will be consistent in size.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have fixed the problem. I have assigned class to the div.

```html
<div class="fill">
  <img src="...">
</div>
```

and in css.

```css
.fill {
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fill img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with `object-fit`.

**Fill** : This will stretch the image to fit the parent disregarding the aspect-ratio.

**Contain**: Preserves the aspect-ratio but may increase or decrease the size of image. Low res scaling up may be distorted.

**Cover**: Keeps the aspect ratio of the image and will fit the parent container but will most likely crop the image.

```css
.img-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.fill {
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Cover</h1>

<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPfiX.jpg" class="cover" />
</div>

<h1>Contain</h1>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPfiX.jpg" class="contain" />
</div>

<h1>Fill</h1>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPfiX.jpg" class="fill" />
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: browser support is the issue, but otherwise would like this option in the future

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing what you want, I've also seen the post where you've answered your own question. Here is one other possible solution. You can play with it and set container `width` and `height` with different values. I've used two pictures. One with `height>width` and the other with `height<width`.
here is also [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLsqj2kb/6/)

```css
.img-container {
  border: 2px dashed #f00;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.img-container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/05/Doctor_Who_-_Current_Titlecard.png" alt="drwho">
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-MkDsiF5-BXQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAKv0/dRBJk-2PGw4/s0-c-k-no-ns/photo.jpg" alt="who2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try both of these options:

```
.card-image {
    background: url(...);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Two notes:
- about 7% of browsers don't support cover;
- using 'fixed' with background can cause unpredictable issues;
- you can also try background-size: contain and see if it gives you better results.

Also, I would recommend reserving some space for the image until it loads, to avoid document reflow when picture begin reloading.

```
.card-container {
    position: relative;
}

.card-image {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; //for 16:9 ratio
}

.card-image img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```