# Shrink height image and it's become distorted

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the image not distorted when it shrinks down the height size? Because I have an image with the size (1080 * 601) and the div (1080 * 442) (that is the reason I want my image become 1080 * 442 too), so the image with 100% width and height: is 75% that I set all that in code then my image stretches too much which makes the font so quirky. I tried background-image but it was not a suitable solution. Are there any properties in CSS that can do that?
Example:

```
<div class="event-img" style="margin-bottom:30px"><img src="/../../../upload/image/Black and Blue Professional Technology Business Project Presentation(6).png" border="0" style="max-height: 75vh"></div>
```

```html
<div class="vec">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DKtbQhs/White-Modern-Clean-Minimalism-Presentation.png" alt="White-Modern-Clean-Minimalism-Presentation" border="0" style="max-height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent image distortion inside a resizing container with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722597/prevent-image-distortion-inside-a-resizing-container-with-css)

Comment: My problem is the max-height: 75vh it's compulsory so it's cannot set to 100%. However, if that happen my image still fine but I can't

Answer (score 0):

You could use `object-fit`

```html
<div class="vec">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DKtbQhs/White-Modern-Clean-Minimalism-Presentation.png" alt="description" style="width: 100%; height: 75vh; object-fit: cover;">
</div>
```

---

You could also use `max-width` and `max-height`

```html
<div class="vec">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DKtbQhs/White-Modern-Clean-Minimalism-Presentation.png" alt="description" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 75vh;">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but my company says they want images for the ad banner it should keep full content so if I use object-fit: cover then some of the content will missing which makes customer cannot see full all content and information the image ad about it

Comment: We have many duplicates of this question and this answer. Please do at least a cursory search before answering.