# Animate/Transition from max-height to fixed height

Tags: javascript, css

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = useState(false);

  const _setClasses = () => {
    if (isMinimized) return "container container-minimized";
    return "container";
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={_setClasses()}>
        <p>Foo</p>
        <p>Bar</p>
        <p>Foobar</p>
        <div
          onClick={() => setIsMinimized(!isMinimized)}
          className="minimize-element"
        >
          <span />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  transition: height 2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  max-height: 60%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-minimized {
  height: 55px;
}

.minimize-element {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.minimize-element:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.minimize-element > span {
  background-color: red;
  width: 35px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I want to animate from a `max-height` which is set in `percentage` to a fixed `height` which is set in `pixel`.

Here is also a codesandbox displaying the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-snowflake-f6p5l9?file=/src/styles.css:0-907

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close! It's just a matter of:

1. Transitioning the `max-height` property
2. Setting the max-height property to the appropriate values

   - When open: `100%`
   - When closed: `55px`

It's worth noting that the parent styles will affect the behaviour of the percentages [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262938/child-with-max-height-100-overflows-parent) discusses that the `max-height` is often based on the parent's `height`.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = useState(false);

  const _setClasses = () => {
    if (isMinimized) return "container container-minimized";
    return "container";
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={_setClasses()}>
        <p>Foo</p>
        <p>Bar</p>
        <p>Foobar</p>
        <div
          onClick={() => setIsMinimized(!isMinimized)}
          className="minimize-element"
        >
          <span />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Body />
    </div>
  );
}

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div className="MainBody">
      <p>p1</p>
      <p>p2</p>
      <p>p3</p>
      <p>p4</p>
      <p>p5</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
      <div>some final content</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-minimized {
  max-height: 55px;
}

.minimize-element {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.minimize-element:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.minimize-element > span {
  background-color: red;
  width: 35px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.MainBody {
  margin-top: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

EDIT: It's also worth considering that the fixed position height should be considered when having adjacent content. In the snippet below I've added a `div` of class `MainBody` and set the `margin-top: 55px` which will mean that the first few elements are not hidden behind the `container` element.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = useState(false);

  const _setClasses = () => {
    if (isMinimized) return "container container-minimized";
    return "container";
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={_setClasses()}>
        <p>Foo</p>
        <p>Bar</p>
        <p>Foobar</p>
        <div
          onClick={() => setIsMinimized(!isMinimized)}
          className="minimize-element"
        >
          <span />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Body />
    </div>
  );
}

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div className="MainBody">
      <p>p1</p>
      <p>p2</p>
      <p>p3</p>
      <p>p4</p>
      <p>p5</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
      <p>another paragraph</p>
      <div>some final content</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container-minimized {
  max-height: 55px;
}

.minimize-element {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.minimize-element:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.minimize-element > span {
  background-color: red;
  width: 35px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.MainBody {
  margin-top: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with CSS as far as I know. You can make it work if you move from a static height to another static height: `height:100px;` -> `height:200px;`

It also works if you transition the max-height itself: `max-height:35%;` -> `max-height:55px;`, but it will shrink from the full 35 percent, even though you may only see about 12% height on the page.

You may need some JS here.