# Cannot resize image in CSS because it overflows a <div>

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow

I have the following code:
JavaScript:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "../Static/white_lotus.jpeg";

import "./LogoSearchProfile_Header.css";
function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-left">
        <div className="header-logo-link">
        <img
              className="header-logo"
              src={logo}
              alt=""
            />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

`LogoSearchProfile_Header.css`:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}


.header-left{
  margin-left: 2%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: inherit;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red ;
}


.header-logo > img {
  height: 20px;
}
```

where I'm using this image (`white_lotus.jpeg`) as my logo:

[image]

Currently, this produces:

[image]

where the `<img>` overflows the `<div>`, and despite everything I try, I can't change the size of the image. Altering the tag `header-logo` does nothing, it seems. Is there anything I can do? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Your image itself has the class `header-logo` and your CSS is selecting its children with `>`. Try changing your CSS from `.header-logo > img` to `.header-logo` or just `img`.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}


.header-left{
  margin-left: 2%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: inherit;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red ;
}


.header-logo {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="header">
  <div class ="header-left">
    <div class ="header-logo-link">
      <img class ="header-logo"
           src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSimC.jpg
           alt=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I do this, the image just stretches: https://ibb.co/jwDBH4y

Even adding `width: 20px` does not help

Comment: Try searching 'prevent image from stretching css'. Here's a result that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380218/3291390.

Comment: Right, but I'm also wondering, why is this happening in my case? It seems it doesn't happen for you or for others...?

Comment: Try running it in a different browser. If your code is the same then I don't know why your results would be different.

Comment: @VictorM Do you have any CSS other than what you posted?

Comment: Yes but I do not use it in the HTML code?

Comment: Well, I don't know then. It may have something to do with React, I'm not familiar with React at all so I wouldn't know about that.

Comment: But I did notice from the image you linked that it looks like it is not the image itself stretching but the entire `.header-left` flex container.

Comment: @VictorM See the **EDIT** portion of my answer. Using a negative `z-index` or `overflow-y: hidden;` should make your image appear like it is not overflowing the height of the div... not a react issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.header-logo > img` is instructing the browser to look at the child of `header-logo` which in fact there is none.

Your `height: 20px` is essentially calling to both the image and the class associated with it, which is unnecessary. I would suggest using one or the other, like below.

**EDIT** ~ you can also use a [negative z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217407/css-negative-z-index-what-does-it-mean) or `overflow-y: hidden;` to have the overflow of the image appear behind the div. So it doesn't appear to be "larger" anymore.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.header-left {
  margin-left: 2%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: inherit;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 20px;
}

/* img {
  height: 20px;
} */
```

```html
<div className="header">
  <div className="header-left">
    <div className="header-logo-link">
      <img class="header-logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/3WWwMHR/CSimC.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Overflow happens when content exceeds parent height. Make content height match parent/container height, or do not set height with arbitrary fixed measurements.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is the following:

```
.header-left > img {
     height: 20px;
}
```

Or

```
.header-logo {
  height: 20px;
}
```

As the img's class is header-logo and the selecter > means an img whose parent has class header-logo which is not the case here.