# Displaying images with adaptive width and fixed aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying images in a grid for a photography website using bootstrap.

Bootstrap takes care of displaying all pictures with the same width. However, I need to find a way to limit the height of vertical pictures to that of their horizontal peers.

The result should be that vertical pictures are cropped into horizontal pictures when displayed in the grid.

I'm using this code to display the images:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
   <a href="img/picture-1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/picture-1.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

or, alternatively:

```
<a class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3" href="img/picture-1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/picture-1.jpg"></a>
```

I'm tried with fixed width and height pixel value, but to no avail.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I rephrased the question. Hope it's clearer now! Basically I'm looking for a way to display all my images, be they horizontal or vertical, into a thumbnail of fixed (horizontal) aspect ratio.

Comment: I guess I'm still not understanding exactly. I don't see a question mark in the entire question, so maybe I missed the rephrasing. It would also help if you would create a Fiddle demonstrating the problem, or a sketch.

Comment: Well the question is: what can I do so all my images, regardless of size and proportion, are all displayed in the same size and proportions? I'll try to make a Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: [CSS Image size, how to fill, not stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch).

Dominic Green's solution:

```
<div class="container"><img src="ckk.jpg" /></div>

.container
     {
      width:300px;
     height:200px; 
     display:block; 
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     }
.container img 
    {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0; 
     width:100%;
     }
```

Its a pain in css to do what you want and center the image, there is a quick fix in jquery such as

```
var conHeight = $(".container").height();
var imgHeight = $(".container img").height();
var gap = (imgHeight - conHeight) / 2;
$(".container img").css("margin-top", -gap);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, why not do something like this:

```
.img-responsive {
    height: 30vh;
}
```

Vertical height `vh` is usually more definitive than just setting a pixel or %age height.

Comment: thanks but that didn't work. However I found the solution: make a fixed sized container (which I'd tried of course), and use the overflow:hidden property!