# Equal height with auto width collage

Tags: css, gridview

I am try to make something like the following image.

[image: Auto Width collage]

The image size can be any size but max height should be 68px

I have tried `table-cell` but i am not able to break the row.

I have also use [column-count](http://jsfiddle.net/Pa7mU/68/) but not get sucess is it possible with css ?

Need help Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is perfect for this, just add this css to the parent of the pictures:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

You can set the `flex-grow` of the children to 1 to stretch them over the whole parent. See the example I made for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/u4cxqab1/

Here is some more documentation about flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: will you please set this layout ? http://jsfiddle.net/Pa7mU/68/ actually i am not familiar with flexbox

Comment: yes exactly but image getting stretch can we fix it ?

Comment: You can add `object-fit: cover` to the img to remove stretching.

Comment: object-fit: cover has browser compatibility issue http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: dude i have another question what should i do if i need 10 image in single row ?

Comment: Yeah well, that's IE :) But maybe this guy answers your question with Polyfill: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29103071/6490884

Comment: and what should i need to do for 10 images in single row like image in question ?

Comment: I would say, make your parent bigger, but since it is in % it will change when resizing the window, so that will screw up the row of 10.