# what is the best way to center image without cropping?

Tags: html, css

[image][![

```css
.img_div{
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
img.prof_img{
      height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='img_div'> <?php echo "<img class='prof_img' src='$location' alt=''>"; ?> </div>
```

**what is the best way to center image without cropping ?**][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtubT.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtubT.png)

Comment: set the width to 100% of `.img_prof_img`

Comment: then it gets squeezed.

Comment: `max-width: 100%, height: auto, display:block` to `.img_prof_img`

Comment: set the image to the background image of a div instead of an img tag. then use `background-size:contain;background-position:center;`

Comment: yeah i made it just instead of background-size:contain; i used background-size:cover; and i get what i wanted  thank u very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
<div class='img_div' style="background-image: url('<?php echo $location; ?>'); background-position: center;"></div>
```

note the use of `background-position: center;`

Comment: Here is a link to the solution http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
.img_div{
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
img.prof_img{
     width: 100%;
}
```

you could even add a

transform: scale(1.1); inside of your img.pro_img selector if you need to center it more..

Comment: i wanna keep height 100% and get margin 0 effect .

Comment: Then just give the .img_div a background image with a background-size: cover;  and remove the image tag out of your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
img.prof_img{
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the picture aspect ratio is different than the container its impossible to make it fill the container.

<strike>As I see in your example, you want to show preview of the uploaded image, **if** you only want to show preview and not modify it as if it was user profile picture then you can do it like [**`this`**](https://jsfiddle.net/tmu6wp4s/2/), its a simple solution and it may work in this case...</strike>
*wont work for tall image.*

Here is a similar [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch) that may help.
Try [**depa's solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763434/2308273)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. From the top of my head.

- Constrain `img` proportions in HTML (but this is [not advised](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no_scale=))
- Set proportions in  CSS
- using the `background-size` with `background-image` property.

i'd recommend going over the last one , as the first two are widely not in use today , unless you are dealing with some rigid CMS .

A fiddle for demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jz9oh8jx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this inserting your image

```css
.container{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
float: left;
background: yellow;
border: solid 1px #000;
text-align: center;
}
.container img{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="Untitled-2.png" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```