# Unwanted image overflow when using slick carousel

Tags: javascript, json, carousel, slick.js

First time caller, long time listener.

I'm trying to fit my pictures into this slick carousel but the vertical portion is always going outside of the boundary. Ideally, I want my pictures to fill the carousel section (cover) and want the size to adapt responsively to screen size changes.

I'm new to coding and have tried a lot. Here are some links to the site where I am right now:

https://codepen.io/jerimijones/pen/WXvBMX

```
#carousel {
  width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;}
```

https://carouseltest.netlify.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you possibly post the code you're trying? Ideally in a CodePen or jsfiddle or just in a ``` code block

Comment: @phocks Just updated the question with a codepen link

Answer (score 0):

A possible duplicate of [CSS Image size, how to fill, not stretch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch)

---

You can use the css property `object-fit`.

```
.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

[See example here](http://codepen.io/afonsoduarte/pen/EaOROW)

There's a polyfill for IE: https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit

Comment: Hey @phocks just added my site to codepen. Here's the link: https://codepen.io/jerimijones/pen/WXvBMX