# CSS Issue with background image

Tags: html, css

I have an interactive webpage.

The body element has a background image.
As soon as new elements are added on the page, the image stretches and I don't want this behaviour.

How do I get this fixed.

```
<style>
     body {
         background-image : url(./image.jpg);
         background-size: cover;
     }
</style>

<body>
      <section>
            ... dynamic elements
      </section>
</body>
```

Comment: please share some before and after screen shots as well

Comment: `background-size:cover` means that the image will stretch to fill its container both horizontally and vertically. If that's not what you want, can you explain what you _do_ want to happen? Maybe a larger image will help.

Comment: just remove background-size: cover line.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `background-size: cover;` from your css, because `cover` property is to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges. So instead of `cover` try to set background size as `px` or `%`.

If you want to stretch horizontal and not vertical try the below code

`background-size: 100% 50%;`

Eg:- `background-size:width(px or % or vw) height(px or % or vh)`

Answer (score -1):

Add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` in body styling.

Comment: I tried that, the background image still zoom in when a button is clicked to add new elements

Comment: `no-repeat` will have no effect in this case, since `background-size:cover` will ensure there is only one instance of the image visible.

Comment: In that case, why don't you give a specific size to the background image?
'height:500px;
width:900px;'