# Trying to make these images all appear as the same equal width and height without looking stretched or weird. Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here's the code!If you scroll all the way to the bottom I list some things I tried already. The pictures do not all have to be in the same row. "Jonathans" picture stretches to the right of the page for some strange reason.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> About Us! </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/aboutus.css?q={{time}}" type="text/css" </head> <div class="about-section">
    <div class="container">

        <h1>About Us Page</h1>
        <p> Meet the team behind this project. </p>
        <p>QuickCook was made by struggling cooks for struggling cooks.</p>
    </div>

    <h2 style="text-align:center">Our Team</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="static/images/img1.jpg" alt="Chelsea" width="100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Chelsea H</h2>
                    <p class="title">Co-Founder, Coding Specialist</p>
                    <p>Chelsea Haye is a freelance full-stack web developer and business analyst. She is studying
                        computer science and mathematics aiming for minors in biochemistry and cosmetology. She has
                        worked as
                        a freelance technology consultant for many startups. She cooks for her family daily and enjoys experimenting with recipes from her multicultural family.</p>
                    <p>chaye@brooklynfriends.org</p>
                    <p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="static/images/img4.jpg" alt="Daniel" width="100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Daniel R</h2>
                    <p class="title">Co-Founder, Financial Manager</p>
                    <p>An entrepreneur and CEO who doesn’t have much experience in cooking, but loves food and try new
                        things. He has inspired many young entrepreneurs.</p>
                    <p>daniel@example.com</p>
                    <p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="static/images/img2.png" alt="Jonathan" width="120%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Jonathan M</h2>
                    <p class="title"> Co-Founder, Financial Advisor</p>
                    <p>An entrepreneur that is experienced in cooking.</p>
                    <p>jonathan@example.com</p>
                    <p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="static/images/img3.jpg" alt="Nancy" width="100%">
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>Nancy C</h2>
                    <p class="title">Co-Founder, Coding Specialist</p>
                    <p>Nancy is a full-stack developer and a food enthusiast who loves experimenting with different
                        foods.</p>
                    <p>sovsauce@gmail.com</p>
                    <p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the css!

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 8px;
}

.about-section {
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#000;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.container::after, .row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.title {
  color: grey;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I have tried fiddling with the width and height with no change or not the change I'd like to see.

Comment: Maybe this post solves your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-not-stretch/11763434 .