# How to fix width of td?

Tags: html, css

I have this `table`:

```
<table style="background: green">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px; height: 50px;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;">
                <img src="mylogo.png" width="177" height="71">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see I have an `image` inside that table cell, which is scaled to `177 x 71 pixels`.

In my cell `td` I sepecify a `width` of `100px` and a `height` of `50 px`.

Inside the `div`, which is a `child` of the `td`, I set `overflow` to `hidden`.

It works fine with the `height`, the `image` is not shown completly (as it should in this example).
But it does not work with the `width`.

Comment: What do you **want** to happen? the image to retain its size but be clipped?

Comment: @vsync yes exactly

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757537/css-image-size-how-to-fill-but-not-stretch)

Comment: Read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/)

Comment: Maybe set the width of the div to "inherit" instead of "100%".

Answer (score 0):

CSS-wise you will want to have a look at setting both the width and the height to 100% of the parent container, or a fixed pixel value. And then making use of the object-fit (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property.

`object-fit: cover` will cause the image to be stretched until it fills the box.

`object-fit: contain` will scale the image up until either width or height has reached the max.

I'd suggest to try them both and have a look at which of the two you will most likely want.