# Adding image to fixed size container without changing the dimensions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed container (200x200px) where I want my images to be loaded. Each image has different sizes and currently I have to either resize the image to the container width or the image looses its proportions.

How can I add a image (not background image) to a container and also show the image without changing its proportions possibly in the center (so if the image is 800x600) it will show the center middle 200x200 of that same image? I don't mind using either PHP or jQuery or some CSS magic to make this work.

I really have no idea how to even start so I hope someone can assist with the procedures or stepping stones as how to do this?

EDIT **

I'm possibly not explaining properly. All of the images are bigger than the 200x200 area allocated to it, the problem with resizing is that once the user clicks on the image it needs to load the same image in a lightbox with the key difference that it loads the same image. So effectively I want to force a "thumbnail" view without hindering the proportions of the image. As some of the images are horizontal and some vertical I figured I would rather show the "center" or whichever corner of the image with 200x200 and have the user click on the image to view the full picture. What I am looking for is a way to almost make the image "act" the same way a background image would, but not be a background image? Does that makes sense and is there something available which can assist?

** SAMPLE IMAGE **
Here is a sample image to illustrate my idea: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=21caxc1&s=6

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300660/how-do-i-center-an-image-if-its-wider-than-its-container/3302072#3302072) might be helpful to you.

Comment: Try https://github.com/bburim/resizer - you will always get image of exact size you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try a css based solution. Give a class attribute for your images like `.resizedimg{width:90%}`. This 90% is relative to the container width not the original image width.

If its not help make it from jquery.
Here is a tool which make the job really good: http://imgscale.kjmeath.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should resize your image from a page speed point of view. It's a waste for a user to download an 800x600 image and have it shrunk down to 200px wide by the browser.

Either way, there are several ways you can do this. Firstly, you can add a `width` attribute to your `img`.

Alternatively, look at using CSS: `.img{ max-width: 200px;`

Comment: this may work but what I am trying to avoid is it changing the proportions of the image, hence why I want the same image to load but almost load it within a container. Adding width will not proportion the image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the width of the image and if the width is bigger than height you reduce the image for the width instead reduce from the height to fill the container something like that:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("image_name.jpg");
if ($width>$height){
   echo'<img src="image_name.jpg" style="width:200px;" alt=""/>';
}
else{
   echo'<img src="image_name.jpg" style="height:200px;" alt=""/>';
}
```