# CSS - How do you make text overflow out both ends of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have this div (a red circle):

http://imgur.com/cwVhrgK

which was made with this CSS:

```
.marker-cluster-div {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
font-size: 12px;
border-radius: 50%;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

How do I make the text in the div flow out both ends of the div equally? I want the text to start slightly to the left of the div, and end slightly to the right of it if it doesn't fit. If the text does fit, have it in the center.

How do I do this in CSS?

Comment: You don't..ideally. Text should be contained in it's div...that's what the div is for. I'd find another way of doing it. However, we need to see the HTML and CSS in order to assist properly.

Comment: I'd advise you not to use the word `float` when not speaking in the context of the CSS `float` property because it's confusing for people. The better word in this scenario is 'overflow'. Also, I'm sure your design problem can be solved without having the text actually overflow your div container.

Comment: @BasR. [Here's something that might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300660/how-do-i-center-an-image-if-its-wider-than-its-container).

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/8kqce49h/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should not have text **actually** flowing out of the 'containing' div.

I would suggest something like this.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/enp6r40o/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
    <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    margin: 50px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}

.circle .text {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:auto;   
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

or..even better - [**JSfiddle Demo (Pseudo-element)**](http://jsfiddle.net/szf5e54q/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.circle:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:auto;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: red;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```css
#circle {
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5sit7vueru0cd1/circle.svg?raw=1') no-repeat center center; 
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
</div>
```

---

---

**Another example** with multiple elements:

```css
.circle {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5sit7vueru0cd1/circle.svg?raw=1') no-repeat center center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
</div>

<div class="circle">
  Lorem ipsum.
</div>

<div class="circle">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your CSS

```css
div.content
{
margin-left:300px; /*just for making div visible for you, you can delete that in your code*/
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
font-size: 12px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: red;
font-weight: bold; 
text-align:center;
}

p.centerText
{
  float:left;
  width:400px; /* you must know your text's width for this code to work */
  margin-top:50px; /* div.content's height/2 */
  background-color:yellow;
  margin-left:-150px  /* (p.centerText's width/2)-(div.content's width/2) */
}

Your HTML
```

```html
<html>
<body>  
  <div class="content">    
    <p class="centerText">
     lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum          
    </p>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/straight-shoota/pen/ophHF?editors=110

**CSS**

```
.marker-cluster-div {
  width: 45px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.marker-cluster-div::before {
  content: "";
  left: 7px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Another solution would be to provide the red dot as a background image.