# CSS Position Image bigger than it's container

Tags: html, css

So I've seen this [How do I center an image if it's wider than its container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300660/how-do-i-center-an-image-if-its-wider-than-its-container)
I have something like this

```
.section-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.section-background-image {
    position: relative;
    right:-30%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.section-background-image img {

    position: relative;
    right:-30%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
    <div class="section-background">

      <div class="section-background-image " data-stellar-ratio="0.4">
        <img src="my_huge_image.png" alt="" style="opacity: 0.3;">
      </div>

    </div>
```

And I want the *right* portion of the image to appear if it does not fit the container, (by default its the top left hand corner portion).

With this code, it doesn't always work on the first browser request (shows top left corner portion of image), but it shows the right positioning on refreshes.

Comment: could try setting an overflow:hidden on the container for the image

Comment: _“With this code, it doesn't always work on the first browser request (shows top left corner portion of image), but it shows the right positioning on refreshes”_ – try specifying the width and height of the image explicitly.

Comment: I want it to be mobile responsive, so I don't plan on hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

If there won't be text in the div, you can use `direction: rtl;`

```
.section-background-image {
  ....
  direction: rtl;
}
```

For vertical aligning, use below css

```
.section-background-image img {
 ...
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/q4o08e8u/1/

Comment: It does the right positioning part, but now only the top ~10% of the image is being shown.

Comment: I was only referring to viewing on Safari. On chrome, it's worse; empty blocks in the left side of the container.

Comment: need vertical center alignment ?