# Prevent an image from changing aspect ratio if certain width of page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm still a bit of a noob at this so sorry if this is obvious. I'm trying to make a blurred background image header and I'm having problems when reducing the width of my browser. As you can see from [this code pen](http://codepen.io/hemynameisben/pen/ONEvGy), when the width of the screen gets too small, the image will start to distort. If you take out the min height line, the aspect ratio stays correct but the image resizes and becomes too small for the header container.

Here's my code :

```
<div class="image-header">
        <img id="blurred-header-bg" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/eIOTsGg9FCVrBc4r2nXaV61JF4F.jpg"/>
</div>
```

and style

```
.image-header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
  #blurred-header-bg {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    margin-top: -25%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

Thanks a lot

edit - I have changed the min-width as suggested but am now having trouble centring the image. Any help with that would be suggested. (Have tried making it display as block and parent text-align to centre to no avail)

edit2 - solved the centring issue thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302072/2891659)

Comment: use 
img {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `width: 100%;` to `min-width: 100%;` and the image will not be distorted but still fill the area.

Comment: That works great thanks. The only problem now the image seems to move downwards and is not centred for the screen.

Comment: If anyone has the same issue with centring images wider than the container I solved it thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3302072/2891659

Comment: try adding **margin-left:0; margin-right:0;** to image's css

Comment: It's because you're using `margin-top` with negative value.

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal Sorry, I wasn't clear. The image was moving downwards on resizing the page however after correcting the horizontal centring this no longer happens. The margin-top required to for centring the image vertically.

Comment: You may also use the background-position property

Comment: I agree with @BrainHappy, generally for such things you should play with `background` CSS properties but since you can't apply that blur filter on background, you'll have to go with `img` tag, but still try to make it positioned with `top` n `left` property.