# Image stretch if smaller shrink if bigger and centered

Tags: html, css

I have a div with fixed height, **variable width**, and overflow hidden:

```
.img-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And images with variable sizes: smaller, wider and taller than the container.

What I need is:

- Stretch the image (vertically or horizontally) when necessary to fill the container
- When stretching, **keep the aspect ratio**
- Centralize the image (vertically and horizontally) when is bigger (**overflow is hidden**)

I've created some examples here: https://jsfiddle.net/sh6f5nfh/

```css
.img-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x220" />
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" />
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x70" />
</div>
```

**Edit:**

This solution solves the problem when the image is wider than the container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302072/740394. But there're some cases missing to answer this question: (eg: smaller image; same width but shorter; taller image; ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would go for the background-image approach. Mainly because you have the incredible "background-size:cover" functionality.

```css
.img-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

  background-color: yellow;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.img-cover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

  background-color: yellow;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-container' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x150)'></div>
<div class='img-container' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/100x220)'></div>
<div class='img-container' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/70x50)'></div>
<div class='img-container' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50x70)'></div>

<div class='img-cover' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x150)'></div>
<div class='img-cover' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/100x220)'></div>
<div class='img-cover' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/70x50)'></div>
<div class='img-cover' style='background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50x70)'></div>
```

For more information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could use `object-fit: contain;`  Note, the current IE11 and Edge don't support it, works fine on all other modern browsers though, see the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

Use `object-fit: cover;` if you need the image to fill the container completely.

For polyfill, check this out: [Polyfill for CSS object-fit property](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit).

```css
.img-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain; /* or cover */
}
```

```html
<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x220" />
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/70x50" />
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x70" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest you can achieve to the background size cover with css only and a img tag

**CSS**

```
    .img-container{
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .img-container img{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6005/5927758528_a2060423e7_b.jpg">
</div>
```

In the fiddle you can find both cases

https://jsfiddle.net/op4f8ad0/